# SQL Query from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

Using PHP and mySQL. I have 4 total tables, AgencyInfo, TypeCodes, PrimarySta and MutualAid.  AgencyInfo has unique ID as the primary.  Typecodes has unique TID as the primary.  PrimarySta and MutualAid have both ID and TID together as their primary key.

I'm trying to create a recordset that will give me records from PrimarySta and MutualAid based on a ID from agencyinfo.  There are 47 static records in TypeCodes.  PrimarySta and MutualAid will have 47 entries(typecodes) per ID.  PrimarySta has ID, TID and 12 INT fields, MutualAid has the same ID, TID and 12 INT fields plus a 13th field(text) called notes.

I'm using a while loop to step through the data.  ID is passed via POST or SESSION.

```
Page Layout
                               Primary Station
TypeCode              P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10 P11 P12
                               Mutual Aid
                      M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10 M11 M12
Notes(M13)
```

This is repeated 47 times, once for each typecode.  I used Dreamweaver to assemble my initial SQL Query, but from my research, it appears it may not be using the best syntax.  I had the following code working with only 2 tables, TypeCodes and PrimarySta, but when I added in MutualAid, something broke.

```
$colname_Display = $_SESSION['sta_id']; }
mysql_select_db($database_DB, $MyDB);
$query_Display = sprintf("SELECT * FROM primarysta, typecodes, mutualaid 
WHERE primarysta.tid, mutualaid.tid = typecodes.tid AND primarysta.id = %s", 
GetSQLValueString($colname_Display, "int"));
```

I'm guessing my problem is with the `primarysta.tid, mutualaid.tid = typecodes.tid` line.  I've seen INNER JOIN used, but can't seem to get the syntax right.

Can anyone help me with proper syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    primarysta a
INNER JOIN
    typecodes b
ON
    a.tid = b.tid
INNER JOIN
    mutualaid c
ON 
    a.tid = c.tid
    and c.tid = b.tid
WHERE 
    a.id = %s -- where the %s is your string
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be giving me the correct data.  Currently the ID's that have data are 1, 2, 6, 7, and 14.  When I hardcode 7 into the query, its giving me back records for all of the IDs.

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to test without the actual data.  I added an and to the last inner join.  See if that helps at all.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have helped.  I tried switching primarysta and typecodes and it seems like it sorts properly on mutualaid.id = %s however instead of having 47 entries, the list repeats itself 5 times.  would another table configuration make it easier?

Comment: Got it to work with a modification to my original query.  Probably not the cleanest or best way to do it, but it works.
`SELECT *
FROM primarysta a, typecodes b, mutualaid c
WHERE (a.tid = b.tid AND c.tid = b.tid) AND (a.id = %s AND c.id = %s)`  Thanks for the help though!  You pointed me in the right direction.